# ScrollView auto-scroll off on android app open

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

I'm appending 5 video players in my app via `java`. When the app opens, the `ScrollView`'s `scroll-Y` is positioned to show the 5th video player. How can I avoid this? How can I turn off auto-scroll so when the app opens, the 1st video player appears and the `scroll-Y` is 0?

`Colors:`

```
<color name="secondary_color">#6CABF7</color>
<color name="light_black">#202125</color>
<color name="dark_black">#0F0F0F</color>
```

`activity_main.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@color/secondary_color"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:tag="yo">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`MainActivity.java:`

```
package com.example.test;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LinearLayout content;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        content = findViewById(R.id.content);

        for (int x=0;x<5;x++) {
            RelativeLayout video_player_box = new RelativeLayout(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
            VideoView player = new VideoView(this);
            TextView details = new TextView(this);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 600);
            param.setMargins(0,0,0,50);
            video_player_box.setLayoutParams(param);

            params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
            player.setLayoutParams(params);
            player.setMediaController(null);
            video_player_box.addView(player);

            params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50);
            params.setMargins(5,5,5,0);
            details.setLayoutParams(params);
            details.setPadding(15,0,0,0);
            details.setText(Integer.toString(x+1));
            details.setTextSize(25);
            details.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_black));
            details.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            video_player_box.addView(details);

            content.addView(video_player_box);
        }
        ((VideoView) ((RelativeLayout) content.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_320x180_60fps_600k.mp4"));
        ((VideoView) ((RelativeLayout) content.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView.getTop());` after adding Views.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting this on my parent  linear layout that comes right as the main child of the scrollview solved the issue for me.
`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants`